# Formalizing Intuition on Limits with Integrals

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

The following is an exercise from Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th Edition:

> Let $\phi(x)$ be a non-negative equation such that $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x$ with $|x|>1$, and with $\int_{-1}^1\phi(x)dx=1$. For all $h>0$, define a function $\phi_h(x)=\frac{1}{h}\phi(\frac{x}{h})$. Show that 
>   $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-1}^1\phi_h(x)f(x)dx=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-h}^h\phi_h(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$$
>   for all functions $f$ that are integrable and continuous at $x=0$.

**My attempt:** I think I have the right idea intuitively, but I don't understand how to use the limit "correctly". I first work with the first portion of the equality,
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-1}^1\phi_h(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$$
First, we can rewrite the expression in terms of the function $\phi$ : 
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-1}^1\phi_h(x)f(x)dx\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{h}\phi(\frac{x}{h})f(x)dx$$
Now let $u=\frac{x}{h}$ with $du=\frac{1}{h}dx$. Now we have 
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-1/h}^{1/h}\phi(u)f(uh)du=\lim_{N\to\infty}\Bigg[\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-N}^{N}\phi(u)f(uh)du\Bigg]$$
*Here is where I have a problem*:
I would like to do something like this
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\Bigg[\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-N}^{N}\phi(u)f(uh)du\Bigg] & =\lim_{N\to\infty}\Bigg[f(0)\int_{-N}^N\phi(u)du\Bigg]
\\ & = f(0)\int_{-1}^1\phi(u)du
\\ & = f(0)\cdot 1=f(0)
\end{align*}
I'm pretty sure I can't simply draw the function $f$ outside of the integral, without evaluating the limit with respect to $N$. I would like to know if this is allowed, or if I am violating some rules regarding limits and integration.

Comment: You need to note that $\phi_h(x)=0$ when $|x|>h$. This proves the first equality, and also shows that there isn't any $\lim_{N\to\infty}$ at all.

Comment: @EclipseSun I get that we can show the first equality holds, but I'm stuck on how to separate $f$ and $\phi$ within the integral. Because I want to show that we end up with $f\cdot\int\phi=f\cdot 1$.

Comment: It is true that $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-1}^1 \phi(u)f(uh) du=\int_{-1}^1 \lim_{h\to 0^+}\phi(u) f(uh)du$ by dominated convergence theorem. But I suppose you are not allowed to use that. Instead, you should try $\epsilon-\delta$.